# Creating an immutable CFArray object - Apple sample doesn't work

Tags: c++, c, macos

For testing I copied following sample code [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFCollections/Articles/creating.html] and compiled it:

```
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

CFStringRef strs[3];
CFArrayRef anArray;

strs[0] = CFSTR("String One");
strs[1] = CFSTR("String Two");
strs[2] = CFSTR("String Three");

anArray = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)strs, 3, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
```

Now I got following error: "No matching function for call to CFArrayCreate"

Why it is not compilable and how to implement it that it is compilable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of the second parameter of `CFArrayCreate()` is `const void **`. So, change the call to:

```
anArray = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void **)strs, 3, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
```

This is really only a problem in C++, because it is a lot stricter about converting to and from `void*`. In C, `void*` converts to other pointer types freely.

Comment: Correct. The name mangler cannot find a match in C++, but it will in C and also in Objective-C.

Comment: @guilleamodeo, this has nothing to do with the name mangler. It's at compile time, not link time.

Comment: Oh. I said that because it looked to me as a link error. 'Not matching found' so on my mind it made sense that the mangler produced a name that didn't match.