# Getting/Generating vCard (.vtf file) from Address Book ID

Tags: objective-c, abaddressbook

Im looking for a way to generate/get an electronic business card (vCard) from contacts using an Address Book ID.

I have been able to do this using the users name using this code

```
    ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, nil);

NSMutableDictionary *object = [_Contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *name = [object objectForKey:@"name"];

CFArrayRef contact = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(ab, (__bridge CFStringRef)(name));

CFDataRef vcard = (CFDataRef)ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople(contact);
```

The only problem is that when I have multiple contacts with the same name (not sure why this happens but I do) Instead of getting a single (vCard) I get multiple vCards and when I send the vCard's instead of saying "Users name" it says electronic business card.

I was hoping there a way to be more exact in which card I'm looking for using the address book Id. Is there anyway to do this?

EDIT 1 
Im getting an error when trying this.

```
int32_t ID = [[selectedObject objectForKey:@"ABID"]intValue];
CFArrayRef contact = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(ab,ID);


CFDataRef vcard = (CFDataRef)ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople(contact);
```

Error message

> [__NSCFType objectEnumerator]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x144e51280 2015-05-18 09:13:34.511 theBoard[6854:240618] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType objectEnumerator]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x144e51280'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what ewan meant:

```
int32_t ID = [[selectedObject objectForKey:@"ABID"]intValue];
ABRecordRef contact = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(ab,ID);
CFArrayRef array = CFArrayCreate(nil, &contact, 1, nil);
CFDataRef vcard = (CFDataRef)ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople(array);
```

just casting a value doesn't make an array.
you have to create one

just in case I didn't get it:
[Creating an immutable CFArray object - Apple sample doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385383/creating-an-immutable-cfarray-object-apple-sample-doesnt-work)

Comment: CFArrayRef array = CFBridgingRelease(@[(__bridge id)contact]);
is giving me an error. and you meant to place "array" inside ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople not "contact" correct?

Comment: edited, check and fix as needed but this is basically it - the other way used cocoa.. this looks nicer - less casting ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID`?  You can then make a `CFArrayRef` with just the one entry, and pass that to `ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople` instead.

Comment: Please see Edit 1. Your answer makes sense but I'm getting an error for some reason